# class property inaccesible due to protection level

Tags: c#, class, oop, access-levels

here are my class declarations

```
public class PlacesAPIResponse
{
    public string formatted_address { get; set; }
    public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
    public Location location { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public Guid id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string reference { get; set; }
    public string[] types { get; set; }
}
public class Geometry
{
    Location location { get; set; }
}
public class Location
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lon { get; set; }
}
```

when i try to access it like this, but i get an "inaccessible due to protection level"

```
PlacesAPIResponse response = new PlacesAPIResponse();
string lon = response.geometry.location.lon;
```

what could i be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make location public. It is private by default.

```
public class Geometry
{
    public Location location;
}
```

And you can access lon as double

```
PlacesAPIResponse response = new PlacesAPIResponse();
double lon = response.geometry.location.lon;
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare your `Geometry.location` field as public:

```
public class Geometry
{
    public Location location;
}
```

By default, when you do not explicitly declare the access modifier for a class member, the assumed accessibility for it is `private`.

From the C# Specification section [10.2.3 Access Modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645626%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> When a class-member-declaration does not include any access modifiers,
>   private is assumed.

---

As an aside, you may also consider making it a property (unless it's a [mutable struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil))

EDIT: In addition, even when you fix the access issue, `Location.lon` is declared as a `double` but you are implicitly assigning it to a `string`. You will need to convert it to a string as well:

```
string lon = response.geometry.location.lon.ToString();
```

Comment: i just tried it but it also added another error "The property or indexer 'Geometry.location' cannot be used in this context because the get accessor is inaccessible

Comment: @DimejiIsola Did you update it to be public? That is: `public Location location { get; set; }`?

Answer (score 0):

The `location` property of `Geometry` doesn't specify an accessibility level.  The default level is `private`.

Answer (score 0):

`Geometry.location` has no access modifier so it is private by default